# Designing non-strict grammar parser with monads in Scala

Tags: parsing, scala, monads, scalaz

I need help designing non-strict grammar parser with monads. Grammar structure looks like:

- header
- section1
- section2
- ...

Each of these sections may be missing and stream may end at any place, so, I need to return what I have parsed so far.

I succeeded to use State monad to structure my parser into functions of type *s => (a, s)* for each section. State *s* holds the rest of the input and the data grabbed at the moment. In Scala-like pseudo-code:

```
val parser = for {
  _ <- readHeader
  _ <- readSection1
  _ <- readSection2
  - <- ...
} yield ()

parser(input)
```

Now, I also want to implement early termination so that parser won't try to read further input on EOF. E.g., if EOF is reached after reading the header, I want to return and don't read further.

Here is what I got so far:

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

object Playground extends App {
  type Stream = String
  type Mined = List[String]
  type ParserState = (Stream, Mined)

  type MyEither[+T] = Either[ParserState, T]

  val s1 = StateT[MyEither, ParserState, Unit] { s =>
    Right((("input at s1", add(s, "header")), ()))
  }
  val s2 = StateT[MyEither, ParserState, Unit] { s =>
    Right((("input at s2", add(s, "section1")), ()))
  }
  val s3 = StateT[MyEither, ParserState, Unit] { s =>
    Left(s)
  }
  val s4 = StateT[MyEither, ParserState, Unit] { s =>
    Right((("input at s4", add(s, "section3")), ()))
  }

  def add(s: ParserState, mined: String): Mined = mined :: s._2

  val parser =
    for {
      _ <- s1
      _ <- s2
      _ <- s3
      _ <- s4
    } yield ()
  println(parser.run(("input", List())))
}
```

Prints:

```
Left((input at s2,List(section1, header)))
```

Is this approach practical? I wonder is there a better solution?

Comment: Looks like Iteratee may also suit my needs.